# Getting error while installing gitosis on windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7-x64, gitosis

Error while installing Gitosis on Windows 7:

> "tty" option detected in CYGWIN environment variable.
>   CYGWIN=tty is no longer supported.  Please remove it from your
>   CYGWIN environment variable and use a terminal emulator like mintty,
>   xterm, or rxvt.

I tried setting CYGWIN environment variable by replacing tty by mintty, but did not work.
Not even sure, where to change it actually.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend not using Gitosis as development on it has been abandoned. The first option usually recommended is [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), but I'm not sure how much success you will encounter on Windows. Luckily, there is an [extensive guide](http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b969ea4d-8d2c-42af-9806-de3631f4df68.aspx).

Comment: thanks, but i am at the middle of the Gitosis installation, if I go for Gitolite, I think some of the steps would create problem, isn't it?

Comment: There's a lot more documentation because Gitolite is in use and currently developed. If you do run into a problem, there's a greater chance that someone will be able to assist you. I would abandon gitosis.

Comment: Thanks, I will install Gitolite.